# Edit "alt" text

Tags: html, css, web

I need to change text styles in `alt` tag.

For example:

```
<img alt="Logo" src="images/logo.jpg" />
```

and I need change to size and color this alt (alt="Logo").

Please, what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you mean the tooltip the browser puts up for the text in the `alt` attribute.

You can't control that directly apart from changing the text itself.

There are Javascript libraries that will allow you to write custom tooltips - lots of [jQuery plugins](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/).

---

Update:

If you mean the text that appears if the image cannot be found, you can use normal CSS rules for fonts and colors to control this.

Comment: tooltips are the title attribute not the alt. alt is for missing images but is used in title if your too lazy to specify it.

Comment: @user980058 - I know that. Did you read the question? The OP seems to be asking about the appearance of the `alt` attribute. What do _you_ think he means? And regardless of what `alt` and `title` are defined as in the spec, some browsers **do** display a tooltip for `alt`.

Comment: it's true that he can't control tooltips, but I was pointing out that he wasn't talking about them :|

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the text, which is shown, when no image is availble – just use CSS, for example:

```
img {
   font-size:20px;
   line-height:1.3em;
   color:#ff0000;
}
```

Comment: The effect varies by browser. E.g., IE lets you style the color but not the font size or font family.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact answer. Its a suggestion. You may probably like `tooltip plugins` to get the desired functionality as specified in [this](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/) page.

Answer (score 0):

did you try setting the font for the img tag? I'm pretty sure I've done it that way in the past.

```
<img ... style="font-size: 150%; color: red;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`alt` tooltips cannot be styled directly.

You can however implement your custom tooltips like this plugin: [jQuery Tooltip](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="styleMe"><img src="..." alt="..." /></span>
```

If you have done your code right, you should NEVER see the alt text.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the ALT Attribute it to specify what image would be where the image is currently, if an error occurs, the image cannot be loaded, or the image cannot be found. Your Browser then interprets the ALT Tag and outputs it's value... For example.

```
<img src="images/images.png" alt="An Image Should Be Here" />
```

If NO Error Occurs and the image CAN be found, etc., your browser will display the Image properly. If an error occurs or the image cannot be found it will display with ALT Text in location where your image should be. The Style of the ALT Text (if displayed) can be defined via CSS. But, usually the browser's default value will display the ALT Text in it's pre-defined manner.

I haven't used ALT Tags to display text of an image onHover, but I have used the TITLE tag to display text of an image onHover.

If you are interested in styling the "Tool-Tip" per se, you may always check out various jQuery/JavaScript plugins and HTML Events to reach what you are gunning for... For example:

http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.html

jQuery Tools > Tooltip Plugin

I hope this all helps my friend,
Thanks,
Aaron